# Can't reopen Table mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've the following procedure which says `can't reopen table` why it is giving this error.Here is the query:

```
DECLARE rangee INT;
DECLARE uid BIGINT;

SET @rangee = plimitRange * 10; 
SET @uid    = puserid;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS Rangee;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Rangee(max BIGINT,min BIGINT);

PREPARE STMT FROM
'INSERT INTO Rangee
select max(postid),MIN(postid) from
(
select wall.postid from wall,posts where  
wall.postid = posts.postid and posts.userid=?
order by wall.postid desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?
)m;
';

 EXECUTE STMT USING @uid,@rangee;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;


 select comments.comment,comments.postid,user.name,comments.userid 
 from user,posts,comments where 
 posts.postID = comments.postid and 
 comments.postid<=(select max from Rangee) and 
 comments.postid>=(select min from Rangee) and posts.userid = puserid and 
 user.userid=comments.userid order by comments.postid desc;
```

Here I am inserting values `min` and `max id's` in a temporary table from another table so that I can then use those values to retrieve my  data in the final query.But in the final query where I am specifying the range i.e the line containing `(select max from Rangee)` and `(select min from Rangee)`  is giving this error.How can I solve it.The values of min and max are returning fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<UPDATE>
```

Then forget about the whole procedure, do it in one query:

```
select comments.comment,comments.postid,user.name,comments.userid 
 from 
 user
 INNER JOIN comments ON user.userid=comments.userid
 INNER JOIN posts ON posts.postID = comments.postid
 WHERE 
 comments.postid <=  
 (select MAX(postid) from
    (
    select wall.postid from wall,posts where  
    wall.postid = posts.postid and posts.userid=?
    order by wall.postid desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?
    )sq1
 )

 and 
 comments.postid >= 
 (select MIN(postid) from
    (
    select wall.postid from wall,posts where  
    wall.postid = posts.postid and posts.userid=?
    order by wall.postid desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?
    )sq2
 ) 
 and 
 posts.userid = puserid 
 order by comments.postid desc;
```

That's it.

```
</UPDATE>
```

old answer...

```
DECLARE rangee INT;
DECLARE uid BIGINT;

SET @rangee = plimitRange * 10; 
SET @uid    = puserid;

PREPARE STMT FROM
'select @max_postid := MAX(postid), @min_postid := MIN(postid) from
(
select wall.postid from wall,posts where  
wall.postid = posts.postid and posts.userid=?
order by wall.postid desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET ?
)m;
';

 EXECUTE STMT USING @uid,@rangee;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;


 select comments.comment,comments.postid,user.name,comments.userid 
 from user,posts,comments where 
 posts.postID = comments.postid and 
 comments.postid<=@max_postid and 
 comments.postid>=@min_postid and posts.userid = puserid and 
 user.userid=comments.userid order by comments.postid desc;
```

You don't need a temporary table at all. Also it would have been bad to do `comments.postid <= (select max from Rangee)` since this could potentially return more than one row. You should have at least used `comments.postid <= (select MAX(max) from Rangee)`.

Also read [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html).

Comment: thnx for the answer @tombom I've already tried this and it works fine but the problem in this is that it will return me `2 results` which i dont want. I only want the result from the last query.The select in the prepare statement will return me a result then my final query will return another result.

Comment: I see. Updated my answer. Don't worry cause the query looks complicated. It won't necessarily run slower or anything. MySQL's optimizers does a pretty good job and detects when subqueries are repeating (with minor differences).

Comment: It is giving the following error `Every Derived Table must have it's own alias`.

Comment: @Mj1992 Now it should work. The subqueries were missing an alias, that's all.

Comment: thnx alot.I was stuck on this from several days.